# React Bootstrap Table - recognising a row

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-table

so I'm working on a editable table from a resultset like this one:

```
data = [
{id: 1, name: 'bob', value: '2'},
{id: 2, name: 'HelloWorld', value: '5'},
{id: 3, name: 'TestName', value: '4'}
];
```

And my table goes like this (I also use a custom editor for name and value):

```
<BootstrapTable data={this.props.data}>
      <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='id'>
        ID
      </TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField="name" dataFormat= { CustomInputFormatter }
      customEditor={ { getElement : CustomInputEditor } } >
        Name
      </TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField="value" dataFormat= { CustomInputFormatter }
      customEditor={ { getElement : CustomInputEditor } } >
        Profile
      </TableHeaderColumn>
    </BootstrapTable>
```

So I was wondering, if I change the name 'TestName' to something else is there a way for me to get the id and value of the same row from the onchange fonction?

This is the render of the customInputEditor class

```
render() {
let { value } = this.state;
let { type } = this.props;
return (
  <div>
    <input type={type || 'text'} ref="inputRef" className="form-control custom-textbox" value={value}
        onChange={this.onChange} onBlur={this.onBlur}/>
  </div>
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your onChange function looks like but you should be able to access the values like so:

```
onChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.id)
    console.log(event.target.value)
}
```